# Use firebase firestore to update textview in different activities

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my Gaming App in Activity A, I have a `RecyclerView` in which I populated the Data using ```FirestoreSnapshot listener``.

I have used the Firebase Firestore Live update feature. And updated the Textview of No of users registered.

In Activity B also, I want the same Realtime Live update feature in the Textview of No of Registered users. If users increase to 5. Textview should update to 5 everywhere.
Do I again need to query the FB Database for this or some kind of singleton class or Interface can be used for the same?

Please provide guidance, I am stuck here for weeks.

[image: Activity A & B]

[image: My Database]

At present I am using the following code to Update the textview.

```
DocumentRefrence  docRef =fb.collection("categories").document(categoryID);       
          docRef
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable 
                                        FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                  **spots.setText(String.valueOf(value.getLong("categoryRegUser")));**

                    }
                });
```

Comment: If you are stuck on choosing one option or the other, just go with the one you think will work best for your case (they both will) and implement it.  We can't really tell you what's best for your app. If you have a specific problem with your implementation, you should post that along with you debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, on the first screen you display a list of objects using a real-time listener attached to a query. This means that each time something in the database changes, you update the view accordingly. On the second screen, I understand that you want to have real-time updates every time the value of the `categoryRegUser` field that exists inside the  `May 22, 2023...` document changes. If that's the case, there is no need to query a collection but to [attach a persistent lister on a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). In this way, you'll only get updates when something inside that particular document changes.

And to answer your question, yes, you need another listener in the second activity that listens to single document.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AlexMamo 
Also by Persistent listner on a single document , do u mean that in Activity B , i need to  fetch the ```categoryRegUser``` by querying the Database by Snapshot listner again?

Comment: Also i want to ask that in Activity B , I have a dialog that pops up when clicked on the Green 'Registration open' button down as seen in the image. The dialog have a textview  Registered user . I want real time update in that also. Will i need another Listner for the dialog ?

Comment: No, that is not a query. You can simply create a reference that points to a single document. And right after that, you can attach a persistent listener to that document. A listener on a query is listening for multiple documents, you only need a single one, as far as I understand. Regarding the dialog, yes, if you need real-time updates,

Comment: You should edit **your** question and that code, not add it as an answer. Please format accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: yes I updated my question. now please check and let me know please  that if I am correct or wrong?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me. What happens when you're using that code? Did you also check the error message?

Comment: Yes its working fine. Real time update is their. But isn't it that coz I am using too many Listeners now?  It will be more costly Firebase operation?
I mean i have to use For Dialog too...And also in Activity C.

Comment: The listeners are cheap. What costs, is the number of reads/writes you perform. That's it.

Comment: Yes it helped very well.